# Results keep starting from the start at the start of new year

Tags: mysql

Hi i need a little help with my code, its nearly right but just one little thing going wrong.

I have 3 columns in my results:

- `entries_per_week` which gets the new entries each week so there
  could be 5 one week 3 the next 8 the next and so on.
- `total_entries` which keeps track of the total entries each week so
  it keeps adding up the 'entries_per_week' column.
- Then the `6WK_total` which adds up the previous 6 weeks total.

So basically adds up 6 of the `previous_total_entries`. I nearly have it working but at the start of a new year the `6WK_total` starts new from that year instead of adding up the entries from the previous year.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT a.*
 , sum(b.total_entries) 6WK_total
FROM 
 ( SELECT x.*
        , SUM(y.entries_per_week) total_entries
     FROM
        ( SELECT YEARWEEK(date_created) week_created
               , COUNT(*) entries_per_week
FROM entries
           GROUP 
              BY week_created
        ) x
     JOIN   
        ( SELECT YEARWEEK(date_created) week_created
                 , COUNT(*) entries_per_week
FROM entries
             GROUP 
                BY week_created
        ) y
       ON y.week_created <= x.week_created

    GROUP
       BY x.week_created
 ) a

JOIN
 ( SELECT x.*
        , SUM(y.entries_per_week) total_entries
     FROM
        ( SELECT  YEARWEEK(date_created) week_created
               , COUNT(*) entries_per_week
FROM entries
           GROUP 
              BY week_created
        ) x
     JOIN   
        ( SELECT YEARWEEK(date_created) week_created
                 , COUNT(*) entries_per_week
FROM entries
             GROUP 
                BY week_created
        ) y
       ON y.week_created <= x.week_created

    GROUP
       BY x.week_created
 ) b
  ON b.week_created BETWEEN a.week_created - (6 - 1) AND a.week_created

GROUP
BY week_created;
```

And what happens, here are some results, notice the stared (**) result, my desired results are below in the other table. It should be 1056 like the desired results table below not 248

```
  +--------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------+
  | week_created | total | total_entries         | 6WK_total |
  +--------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------+
  |       201149 |     49| 131                   |       243 |
  |       201150 |     37| 168                   |       411 |
  |       201151 |     37| 205                   |       614 |
  |       201152 |     18| 223                   |       837 |
**|       201201 |     25| 248                   |       248 |**
  |       201202 |     33| 281                   |       529 |
  |       201203 |     66| 347                   |       876 |
  |       201204 |     70| 417                   |       1293|
  |       201205 |     61| 478                   |       1771|
  |       201206 |     88| 566                   |       2337|
  |       201207 |     72| 638                   |       2727|
  |       201208 |     72| 710                   |       3156|
  |       201209 |     67| 777                   |       4030|
  +--------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

Desired results, notice at week_create '201206' the 6 week total would be the 6 results previous in the total_entries so it would be 566 + 478 + 417 + 347 + 281 + 248 = 2337.

```
+--------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------+
| week_created | total | total_entries         | 6WK_total |
+--------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------+
|       201149 |     49| 131                   |       243 |
|       201150 |     37| 168                   |       411 |
|       201151 |     37| 205                   |       614 |
|       201152 |     18| 223                   |       837 |
|       201201 |     25| 248                   |       1056|
|       201202 |     33| 281                   |       1256|
|       201203 |     66| 347                   |       1472|
|       201204 |     70| 417                   |       1127|
|       201205 |     61| 478                   |       1989|
|       201206 |     88| 566                   |       2337|
|       201207 |     72| 638                   |       2727|
|       201208 |     72| 710                   |       3156|
|       201209 |     67| 777                   |       4030|
+--------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm following everything you wrote, but if I am, then your problem seems to be in the YEARWEEK function that you're using to extract the week.

Here's what's happening in your example above. When the YEARWEEK function is applied to the first week of 2012, it resolves to '201201', but when the YEARWEEK function is applied to the last week of 2011, it comes out to '201153'. Since there aren't 100 weeks in a year, the between clause at the end of your query fails at the beginning of the year because the previous month is 201153 not 201199.

If you keep the week added field in a date format and only apply the YEARWEEK function in the outer query, you can use the DATE_SUB() function to do your week subtraction for you. That might look something like `BETWEEN DATE_SUB(week_created, INTERVAL 5 WEEK) AND week_created`.